# Liferay + JSON + jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, liferay

I want get parameters from json, so I have a code:

```
    @RenderMode(name = "VIEW")
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws PortletException, IOException {
            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

            resourceRequest.setAttribute("resourceUrl", "http://localhost:8080/");

             jsonObject.put("rowsPerPage", 10);
             jsonObject.put("page", 1);
             jsonObject.put("total", 100);

             PrintWriter writer = resourceResponse.getWriter();
             writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        }
```

What should be written in JavaScript method that displays the: rowsPerPage, page, total

I have a JavaScript code:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/', function(jd) {
      alert(jd.rowsPerPage);
   });
```

JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <portlet:resourceURL var="testURL" id="view.jsp" escapeXml="false" />
<br/><br/>
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
<div id="pager" style="width:600px;height:20px;"></div>
```

But it is wrong, why?

Comment: U just gave the javascript code, where is the JSP in which this is written? Where is the code which triggers this javascript to run?

Comment: I updated my post, and I want alert() with for example rowsPerPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your URL `http://localhost:8080/` if it returns a JSON response (you can directly paste the URL in the address bar of the Browser). This would return the Welcome page of Liferay.

For calling the `serveResource` method you would require a `resourceURL` to be passed in the jQuery function `getJSON` which can be generated using the `<liferay-portlet:resourceURL>` or `<portlet:resourceURL>` tags in JSP.

**Update:**

You should use the `resourceURL` in the javascript:

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="testURL" id="view.jsp" escapeXml="false" />

<script>
    $.getJSON('${testURL}', function(data) {
        alert(data.rowsPerPage);
    });
</scrip>

<!-- ${testURL}: This is EL i.e. expression language of JSP. Don't confuse it with jQuery -->
<!-- <%=testURL.toString() %>: You can also use scriptlet instead of using EL. But normally scriptlets as you might know are not recommended -->
```

Also I would like to suggest to make sure that the `serveResource` method is actually called with the script by included some log statements in the method.

Here are some links for examples as to how to use Ajax in Liferay:

1. A working [example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxjqueryportl/files/) to use Ajax in Liferay.
2. [Blog](http://ajax-and-portlets.blogspot.in/2011/09/ajax-best-practice-in-portlets.html) explaining concept as to how ajax works in a portal with a simple example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it return Welcome page of Liferay, it is wrong? How can I change it?

Comment: OK, but it is not good. Function alert() don't execute. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Probably serveResource isn't called, so how can I change it?

Comment: @faszynski Can you elaborate on the structure of your portlet, like which file contains the `serveResource` code and which contain the jsp and javascript code. The JSP seems incomplete to me. And also how you are calling the javascript function. Is the javascript function called at all? Try using firebug addon in your mozilla firefox to see if there is a javascript error.

Comment: @faszynski You add `System.out.println` calls to the `serveResource` method or add loggers like first declare a logger `private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(YourPortlet.class);` then use it in the method `_log.error("This is the serve resource method")`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added System.out.println, and it not execute, so How i Can execute serveResource

Comment: @faszynski Kindly tell me, is the javascript `getJSON` executed? Please paste more code as to how the `getJSON` method is executed in the JSP. Also have you checked with firebug if there are any javascript errors? I have a feeling that you are not executing the javascript method properly.

Comment: @faszynski Have updated my answer and have included some relevant links at the end to help you understand better how to use `serveResource` method and ajax in general.